# microk8s Kubernetes Service connection refused

Tags: django, kubernetes, dockerfile, microk8s

I have a simple restful django project that return 'hello world' when you GET localhost:8000.
I want to run it using microk8s.
Using following instruction (https://microk8s.io/docs/registry-images) i created the image and apply my yaml file

yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-deployment
  labels:
    app: hello
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: hello1:local
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello
  ports:
  - name: hello
    port: 8000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000
```

The pod is running properly.

```
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/hello-deployment-6567ccc4f7-7j6nj   1/1     Running   0          61m

NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/hello        ClusterIP   10.152.183.241   <none>        8000/TCP         59m
```

but when i want to access the 10.152.183.241:8000 nothing works.

I also connect to pod by following command

```
microk8s kubectl exec -it hello-deployment-6567ccc4f7-7j6nj -- bash
```

then install curl and test these:

```
root@hello-deployment-6567ccc4f7-7j6nj:/code# curl localhost:8000
Hello World
root@hello-deployment-6567ccc4f7-7j6nj:/code# curl 10.152.183.241:8000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.152.183.241 port 8000: Connection refused
```

Obviously the program is running but there is a problem with kubernetes service. what's wrong with my yaml file?

**Update 1:**
found that image file have problem and it's work with other images.
still don't know what is the problem.

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
CMD python3 manage.py runserver
EXPOSE 8000
```

Comment: You can paste the output of curl -v <IP/localhost>. This will give you verbose output and help other members.

Comment: Cluster-ip is internal to the cluster itself, it can't be accessed from the outside unless it is explicitly exposed - either by NodePort service type or Ingress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't respond.

change

```
CMD python3 manage.py runserver
```

with

```
CMD python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

also add 0.0.0.0 to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Answer (score 3):

It's due to you are using the **ClusterIP** which is only accessible internally from CLuster.

Here you require the **Nginx** ingress controller to expose the service. Or you can try with the Host IP once to connect with the service.

You can also try the command

```
kubectl port-forward svc/hello 8080:8080
```

once the port is forwarded you can hit the `curl` on **localhost:8080**.

However, for production use-case it's always suggested to use the `ingress` for managing the cluster traffic.

Ingress basically work as the Proxy it's same as Nginx.

**Ingress** is configuration object which managed by the `Ingress controller`. When you enable the ingress you require the Ingress controller in minikube it will be there however for other Cluster on **GKE & EKS** you have to setup manually.

Here is good example for the implementation of the ingress in minikube :

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

ingress example

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: hello
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an [ingress add-on](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-ingress), which will let you create rules to access your service via HTTPS/HTTP.

First enable ingress:

```
    microk8s enable ingress
```

Then add an ingress rule to your yaml file, such as:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: http-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: hello
          servicePort: 80
```

Alternatively, you can just expose your port 8000, since you're working locally, as explained [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by my local k8s cluster, *minikube* .
The service ClusterIP didn't help.

To see your deployment , you need to run the following command:

```
minikube service django-service --url
```

Then simply access the urls returned, and there should be your app :)
Also, I have added, just to be safe, the following command, which makes the app visible in the whole local network.

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']